# Bulk update/upsert in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, batch-file, bulk, upsert, nosql

Is it possible to do bulk update/upsert (not insert) in MongoDB?

If yes, please point me to any docs related to this?

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible yet: see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command line program **mongoimport** it should be in your MongoDB bin dir ...

There are two options you'll want to look into to use **upsert** ...

> --upsert                insert or
>   update objects that already exist
>   --upsertFields arg      comma-separated fields for the query
>   part of the 
>                             upsert. You should make sure this is indexed

More info here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Or just do ...

```
$ mongoimport --help
```

Comment: Note: currently --upsert isn't documented in the online docs (they need to be updated) ... but you will see it from the command line --help.

Answer (score 3):

mongo can execute `.js` file.
you can push all you update commands in a js file.

***t.js***

```
db.record.update({md5:"a35f10a8339ab678612d1f86be08b81a"},{$set:{algres:[]}},false,true);
db.record.update({md5:"a35f10a8339ab678612d1f86be08b81b"},{$set:{algres:[]}},false,true);
```

then,
`mongo 127.0.0.1/test t.js`

Answer (score 1):

Bulk updates can also be done in batches as found in the documentation:

[MongoDB Bulk Methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#bulk-methods)

I use these to import CSV files that I need to massage a bit before importing the data.  Its kinda slow when dealing with updates, but it did my 50K document updates in about 83 seconds, which is far slower than mongoimport command.