# Fast or Bulk Upsert in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, upsert, nosql

How can I do a bulk upsert in pymongo? I want to Update a bunch of entries and doing them one at a time is very slow.

The answer to an almost identical question is here: [Bulk update/upsert in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444023/bulk-update-upsert-in-mongodb)

The accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question. It simply gives a link to the mongo CLI for doing import/exports.

I would also be open to someone explaining why doing a bulk upsert is no possible / no a best practice, but please explain what the preferred solution to this sort of problem is.

Answer (score 59):

Modern releases of pymongo ( greater than 3.x ) wrap bulk operations in a consistent interface that downgrades where the server release does not support bulk operations. This is now consistent in MongoDB officially supported drivers.

So the preferred method for coding is to use [`bulk_write()`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) instead, where you use an [`UpdateOne`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateOne) other other appropriate operation action instead. And now of course it is preferred to use the natural language lists rather than a specific builder

The direct translation of the old documention:

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne

operations = [
    UpdateOne({ "field1": 1},{ "$push": { "vals": 1 } },upsert=True),
    UpdateOne({ "field1": 1},{ "$push": { "vals": 2 } },upsert=True),
    UpdateOne({ "field1": 1},{ "$push": { "vals": 3 } },upsert=True)
]

result = collection.bulk_write(operations)
```

Or the classic document transformation loop:

```
import random
from pymongo import UpdateOne

random.seed()

operations = []

for doc in collection.find():
    # Set a random number on every document update
    operations.append(
        UpdateOne({ "_id": doc["_id"] },{ "$set": { "random": random.randint(0,10) } })
    )

    # Send once every 1000 in batch
    if ( len(operations) == 1000 ):
        collection.bulk_write(operations,ordered=False)
        operations = []

if ( len(operations) > 0 ):
    collection.bulk_write(operations,ordered=False)
```

The returned result is of [`BulkWriteResult`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.BulkWriteResult) which will contain counters of matched and updated documents as well as the returned `_id` values for any "upserts" that occur.

There is a bit of a misconception about the size of the bulk operations array. The actual request as sent to the server cannot exceed the 16MB BSON limit since that limit also applies to the "request" sent to the server which is using BSON format as well.

However that does not govern the size of the request array that you can build, as the actual operations will only be sent and processed in batches of 1000 anyway. The only real restriction is that those 1000 operation instructions themselves do not actually create a BSON document greater than 16MB. Which is indeed a pretty tall order.

The general concept of bulk methods is "less traffic", as a result of sending many things at once and only dealing with one server response. The reduction of that overhead attached to every single update request saves lots of time.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand, why you divide your batches in your loop if you know that your driver does it by itself. I mean in your example, 1000 docs of `UpdateOne({ "_id": doc["_id"] },{ "$set": { "random": random.randint(0,10) } })` are less than 16 Mb and it's obvious thus pymongo can split your data and request will be success. Why do you split your data by your hands?

Comment: @Budulianin because it's iterating a cursor and it's very much and anti-pattern to load the whole collection into memory. That's basically why they are batched at reasonable size. Also this needs to go over a nework, and especially with consideration for async environments ( where the basic technique remains the same ) you can basically be sending data across the wire and building another batch whilst waiting for acknowledgement. If you think you gain something by making "one huge batch" as opposed to "several reasonable ones"  then in most cases I would say that's unlikely

Comment: I know this answer is about 4 years old now, but would `update_many` be a valid alternative?

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many

Comment: @Tomiwa can you pls provide an example with `update_many`? At first I tried with `update_many` but couldn't make a proper query or use of it. It's 2021 and I'm still using the answer of @Neil Lunn

Comment: Here is an example

```db.restaurant.updateMany({ violations: { $gt: 4 } }, { $set: { "Review" : true } });
```

Taken from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#examples

Answer (score 33):

MongoDB 2.6+ has support for bulk operations.  This includes bulk inserts, upserts, updates, etc.  The point of this is to reduce/eliminate delays from the round-trip latency of doing record-by-record operations ('document by document' to be correct).

So, how does this work?  Example in Python, because that's what I'm working in.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.version
'2.7rc0'
```

To use this feature, we create a 'bulk' object, add documents to it, then call execute on it and it will send all the updates at once.  Caveats:  The BSONsize of the collected operations (sum of the bsonsizes) cannot be over the document size limit of 16 MB.  Of course, the number of operations can thus vary significantly, Your Mileage May Vary.

Example in Pymongo of Bulk upsert operation:

```
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('myserver', 8839)
db = conn['mydbname']
coll = db.myCollection
bulkop = coll.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
retval = bulkop.find({'field1':1}).upsert().update({'$push':{'vals':1}})
retval = bulkop.find({'field1':1}).upsert().update({'$push':{'vals':2}})
retval = bulkop.find({'field1':1}).upsert().update({'$push':{'vals':3}})
retval = bulkop.execute()
```

This is the essential method.  More info available at:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc1/examples/bulk.html

Edit :- since version 3.5 of python driver, initialize_ordered_bulk_op is deprecated. Use bulk_write() instead. [ http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write ]

Comment: Isn't there any way to avoid doing a find per every operation ? Consider I want to upsert a list of json objects that are embedded in a document, this way, I have to find that document everytime and upsert, this doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: This is just MongoDB's way of writing things, not my idea. In any upsert or update, you have to find the docs you want to update, and that find specifies which ones to act upon.  ALSO, it's supposed to be efficient for large groups of actions, but not necessarily for your specific application, so, as they say, Your Mileage May Vary.

Comment: The `initialize_ordered_bulk_op()` syntax is now deprecated: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/changelog.html?highlight=initialize_ordered_bulk_op

Answer (score 12):

if you have many data, and you want to use "_id" for judge if data exist,

you can try...

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import UpdateOne
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db=client['sampleDB']

collectionInfo = db.sample

#sample data
datas=[
    {"_id":123456,"name":"aaa","N":1,"comment":"first sample","lat":22,"lng":33},
    {"_id":234567,"name":"aaa","N":1,"comment":"second sample","lat":22,"lng":33},
    {"_id":345678,"name":"aaa","N":1,"comment":"xxx sample","lat":22,"lng":33},
    {"_id":456789,"name":"aaa","N":1,"comment":"yyy sample","lat":22,"lng":33},
    {"_id":123456,"name":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","N":1,"comment":"zzz sample","lat":22,"lng":33},
    {"_id":11111111,"name":"aaa","N":1,"comment":"zzz sample","lat":22,"lng":33}
]

#you should split judge item and other data 
ids=[data.pop("_id") for data in datas]

operations=[UpdateOne({"_id":idn},{'$set':data},upsert=True) for idn ,data in zip(ids,datas)]

collectionInfo.bulk_write(operations)
```

My English is very poor, if you can't understand what I say, I'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

The answer remains the same: no support for bulk upserts.

Comment: This is no longer the case. See Kevin's answer.

Comment: Bulk.find.upsert() https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can update all documents that match your query spec using multi=True.

There is a bug [here](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2172?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel) about doing a batch of commands the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest bulk update with Python 3.5+, motor and asyncio:

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import logging
import random
import time

import motor.motor_asyncio
import pymongo.errors


async def execute_bulk(bulk):
    try:
        await bulk.execute()
    except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as err:
        logging.error(err.details)


async def main():
    cnt = 0
    bulk = db.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    tasks = []
    async for document in db.find({}, {}, no_cursor_timeout=True):
        cnt += 1
        bulk.find({'_id': document['_id']}).update({'$set': {"random": random.randint(0,10)}})
        if not cnt % 1000:
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(execute_bulk(bulk))
            tasks.append(task)
            bulk = db.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    if cnt % 1000:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bulk.execute(bulk))
        tasks.append(task)
    logging.info('%s processed', cnt)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')    
db = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()['database']['collection']
start_time = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    execution_time = time.time() - start_time
    logging.info('Execution time: %s', datetime.timedelta(seconds=execution_time))
```

Comment: Why the modulo 1000? I thought mongo bulk operations 'automatically' execute on 2000 operations in a go...

Comment: @duhaime Nice question. I can refer to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Bulk-Operation-Size), but looks like [16MB limit for BSON](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24238349/4249707) will be more precise value. Unfortunatly I have no idea how to measure the requests size

Comment: @duhaime BTW, according to lastest motor [docs](http://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html#bulk-insert) we can not worry about it at all

Comment: this solution gives me the following error: AttributeError: type object 'MongoClient' has no attribute 'topology_description'. It seems to be related to the motor library. Any ideas?

Comment: @user6400946 this answer is too old, you can try to follow up to date motor [documentation](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/bulk.html#bulk-insert)