# Is it possible to modifiy MongoDB InsertBatch operation?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wonder if there is an option to change the default batch size of 1000 document while using the InsertBatch Operation from the WriteMongoCollectionProxy.

I am creating an IEnumerable with about 1-2 million objects and trying to save it fast in MongoDB unsing the InsertBatch Methode.

```
>     var concern = Collection.GetWriteMongoCollection().InsertBatch(entityList);
>     if (!concern.Any(x => x.HasLastErrorMessage && !x.HasLastErrorMessage))
>     {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
```

My problem is that the generated data is slow saved in the MongoDB. For each 1.000 objects it might take 8 seconds. Trying to insert 1.000.000 objects cost 8000 seconds --> 133,33 mins. So more than 2h and 13 mins.

When i will reach an amount of data about 10.000.000 objects i will need more than 22h to save the objects in MongoDB. That will be too long... Is there any option to improve that?

I already checked the MongoDB documentation for options, but I was unable to find something usefull. Any suggestions or ideas how to change that limit and save data faster?

With that question i am refering to : [What is MongoDB batch operation max size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237887/what-is-mongodb-batch-operation-max-size/50837989?noredirect=1#comment88679683_50837989)

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/ suggests it is a Mongo feature that cannot be overwritten.

Comment: I'm curious if you're reaching a disk-write limit, rather than a limitation in Mongo. What hardware is the Mongod service running on?

Comment: I am using using multiple devices. 1 devices is gernerating data and trying to store it on another server with mondob installed. The "worker" has a Intel core i7-3370 CPU @ 3.40 GHz, 4 cernal, 8 processor, 32 GB RAM installed.

Comment: I can see... thank you mjwill, but "The sizes and grouping mechanics are internal performance details and are subject to change in future versions." If I understand that right, it seems, that MongoDB might will change that in the next versions?...