# pymongo find_one_and_update performance on millions of inserts/updates

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb-query, pymongo

> **Update:** If you read this to improve your insert/update speeds, check if you have pymongo C extensions enabled on your system by running `pymongo.has_c()` from a python console first. If it resolves to `False`, you either need to compile pymongo with C extensions or do `pip install --upgrade pymongo`
>
> It improved my workflow from 17 seconds on 10K rows to about 0.57 seconds.

I have thousands of txt files, containing millions of rows of data that I am trying to import into a mongodb collection.

I'm currently using the following **def**:

```python
import re, pymongo
coll = pymongo.MongoClient().database.collection
rx = re.compile(r'[:; ]')
rx_email = re.compile(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+$')

def parser(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                fields = rx.split(line.decode('utf-8'))
                email = ''
                username = ''
                for field in fields:
                    if rx_email.match(field):
                        email = field
                    elif field != fields[-1]:
                        username = field
                password = fields[-1]
                if email:
                    coll.find_one_and_update({'email': email}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)
                elif username:
                    coll.find_one_and_update({'username': username}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)
                else:
                    pass
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser('path/to/file.txt')
```

When I try to run the script on a file with 10K rows, it took 74.58974479999999 seconds. I assume this is due to the amount of items MongoDB has to match against when I insert?
Running the same loop without db interaction took 0.022998 seconds.

*EDIT*: As suggested in [Fast or Bulk Upsert in pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292370/fast-or-bulk-upsert-in-pymongo), I have also tried to use `UpdateOne` with `bulk_write` as follows:

```
def parser(path):
    ops = []
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        for line in f:
            if (len(ops) == 1000):
                LOCAL_DB.bulk_write(ops, ordered=False)
                ops = []
            try:
                fields = rx.split(line.decode('utf-8'))
                email = ''
                username = ''
                for field in fields:
                    if rx_email.match(field):
                        email = field
                    elif field != fields[-1]:
                        username = field
                password = fields[-1]
                if email:
                    pass
                    ops.append((UpdateOne({'identifier': email}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)))
                elif username:
                    pass
                    ops.append((UpdateOne({'identifier': username}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)))
                else:
                    pass
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
```

Time to complete 10K lines is 17 seconds, which is however way to slow for the amount of files and rows I am trying to update.

Are there any better (and hopefully faster) ways of doing this?

Some requirements:

1. email and/or username should be unique.
2. The array containing passwords should only list each password once (also unique).
3. 1M rows should (if possible) take less than 1 minute to insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast or Bulk Upsert in pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292370/fast-or-bulk-upsert-in-pymongo)

Comment: I don't think that solution is what I am looking for. Or at least not in the form it is presented there.

Comment: Do you have a unique index on `identifier`?

Comment: Yes I do (Ascending), If I try with larger files (say 1M rows), after 34200 inserts it just stops.

Comment: Then that's likely as fast as you can make it. Although it stopping after 34200 inserts may indicate a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: I was hoping to find something around pre-encoding it to BSON before insertion could speed this up even further, but I haven't found much information other than "users shouldn't normally need to encode to BSON"

Comment: I found out that `pymongo.has_c()` resolved to false on my system, after doing `pip install --upgrade pymongo`, I got 10K lines down to 0.57 seconds (also making sure that C extensions was `True` aftwerwords.).

Comment: That's great! Go ahead and add that as an answer (and accept it). Or add a new answer to the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I managed, with some guidance by @JohnnyHK in the comments, to get my initial `upsert` time from ~74 to ~0.5 seconds for 10K rows by doing the following to my initial code:

```python
import re, pymongo
rx = re.compile(r'[:; ]')
rx_email = re.compile(r'\S+@\S+\.\S+$')

def parse(path):
    ops = []
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        for line in f:
            if (len(ops) == 1000):
                pymongo.MongoClient().database.collection.bulk_write(ops, ordered=False)
                ops = []
            try:
                fields = rx.split(line.decode('utf-8'))
                email = ''
                username = ''
                for field in fields:
                    if rx_email.match(field):
                        email = field
                    elif field != fields[-1]:
                        username = field
                password = fields[-1]
                if email:
                    ops.append((pymongo.UpdateOne({'_id': email}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)))
                elif username:
                    ops.append((pymongo.UpdateOne({'_id': username}, {'$addToSet': {'passwords': password}}, upsert=True)))
                else:
                    pass # logic removed
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass # logic removed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(path/to/file.txt)
```

I found that [pymongo C extensions](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v1.3/monitoring/tutorial/building-pymongo-packages-with-c/) was missing on my system:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.has_c()
>>> False
```

From there I did `pip install --upgrade pymongo` (luckily for me)
and it resolved to True

I also used `_id` instead of `identifier` for the unique fields, which improved speed even more.

Hope this helps people down the road. I will update with more findings as I learn.